# Error message generating for every input for an empty list case

Tags: haskell

I'm doing my second assignment in my first semester of learning coding using haskell, so I'm quite new to coding. My problem is that every input I test, empty or not, generates my error message for the empty case, why would this be?

Type classes added for clarity. This is also part of an assignment so please only guide me for this one error :')

```
type Histogram a = Map a Int
inc :: Ord a => Histogram a -> a -> Histogram a

create
  :: Ord a
  => Histogram a -> [a] -> Histogram a
create h (head:restOfString) = create (inc h head) restOfString
create h [head]              = inc h head
create h []                  = error "No elements in string"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong:

```
create h (head:restOfString) = ...
create h [head]              = ...
```

when passing a list containing only one element, the *first* branch matches, with `restOfString` being empty. Hence, the second branch will never be taken.

Put the second line first.

If you turn on warnings with `-Wall`, GHC warns about many potential problems, including this one. I recommend it.

Comment: So simple! I guess I just assumed a list with 1 element would pass by that but I didnt consider that restOfString could be empty too.

Answer (score 0):

Your first two patterns overlap, so the first one always takes precedence over the second one. Swap them.

This triggers a warning by default in GHC, remember to read the compiler's output. For a better coding experience, it is also advisable to enable `-Wall`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't understand why it would be "redundant", but chi's answer cleared that up for me